# jsonp not working on my webserver

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, jsonp

I'm new to JSONP and I'm trying to access a cross domain file hosted on my webserver.

UPDATE: I found another solution to fix my issue: I used CORS for JQUERY of http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Here is my js file:

```
var url = "myip:port/pgif.jsonp?callback=?"
var url2 = "http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?";
$.getJSON(url2, {
            tags: "jquery",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        }, function (data) {
            console.log("d= ", data);
            });
        }
    );
```

When I try with url2, it works well but when I try with url to access my file on my webserver it doesn't.

Here is what I can see in the Network tab of Chrome Dev tools with url2 which works:

```
Request URL:http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=jQuery19107969533477444202_1386114768597&tags=jquery&tagmode=any&format=json&_=1386114768598
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Cookie:__utma=189990958.626465526.1385955515.1385955515.1385955515.1; __utmc=189990958; __utmz=189990958.1385955515.1.1.utmcsr=sarajchipps.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/2011/01/using-jquery-ajax-calls-in-a-chrome-plugin.html
Host:puppygifs.tumblr.com
Proxy-Authorization:Negotiate 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
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://ip:port/MyApp/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
callback:jQuery19107969533477444202_1386114768597
tags:jquery
tagmode:any
format:json
_:1386114768598
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:max-age=900
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/javascript
Date:Tue, 03 Dec 2013 23:52:57 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 03 Feb 2013 12:02:52 GMT
P3P:CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL"  
Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:X-UA-Device
Via:1.1 SYDTMG01
X-Cache-Metadata:
X-Robots-Tag:noindex
X-UA-Device:desktop
```

Here is what I can see in the Network tab of Chrome Dev tools with url which doesnt work:

```
Request URL:http://ip:port/pgif.jsonp?callback=jQuery1910627754604909569_1386116200762&tags=jquery&tagmode=any&format=json&_=1386116200763
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Host:ip:port
Referer:http://ip:port/MyApp/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
callback:jQuery1910627754604909569_1386116200762
tags:jquery
tagmode:any
format:json
_:1386116200763
Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:6616
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 02:02:33 GMT
ETag:"68647623"
Last-Modified:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:23:16 GMT
Server:lighttpd/1.4.30
```

So as you can see, in the last one, I added Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* in the config of my lighttpd webserver, which doesnt improve the situation.

so I dont really understand, I receive an Ok answer from the webserver but my success function is never called.

Here is the JSONP file I'm trying to access on my webserver:

```
var tumblr_api_read = {"tumblelog":{"title":"puppy gifs"},"posts-start":0,"posts-total":"18"}
```

Comment: what is the value returned by your server

Comment: status code:200, I uploaded what the server returns in each case

Comment: So, I didn't managed to make the JSONP work with my web server but I found a different way to solve my problem.

I followed the "CORS from JQuery" from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/
And I'm now able to read my file sitting on my webserver.


It seems like if I want to edit my file, I would need to configure my web server to be able to handle the preflight request.

As explained in https://x3dom.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notes/cors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't managed to make the JSONP work with my web server but I found a different way to solve my problem:
I followed the "CORS from JQuery" from html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors
And I'm now able to read my file sitting on my webserver.

It seems like if I want to edit my file, I would need to configure my web server to be able to handle the preflight request. As explained in x3dom.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notes/cors.html